# How can I prevent a user from making the browser window narrower than a predefined width in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, browser, window, width

I would like to know how I can prevent a user from making the browser window containing my webpage narrower than a predefined width, since the minimum width of the browser window that Firefox automatically defines will break my layout. How can I do so? Thanks!

Comment: Compeltly wrong approach. instead fo trying to manipulate the users browser (Which you cant) you should fix the issues at your end. Besides you cant force the users browser to be bigger then his screen. Besides that it is also a bad approach then fixing your real non-responsive design issues, you can declare a minimum width with the body selector combined with an overflow `body { min-width: 1000px; overflow-x: scroll; }`

Comment: @tacoshy Well, I'm not trying to force the browser to be bigger than the user's screen; I'm trying to force the browser not to be smaller than a certain value, unless you mean if the user's screen is, for example, 300px wide (maybe they're on a phone), and I limited it to 400px. Do you mean that? Thanks!

Comment: exactly that. Trying to enforce a browser with is not possible in a normal way. Also makes no sense. Like you realized yoruself, if you try to enforce a browser width of 400px but the suers screen is smaller then this would be technically impossible. That why youcgive the body a minimum width with overflow-x: scroll. Thatw ay the webpage will always have a minimum width and if the browser is smaller then that, youc an a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @tacoshy Then what do you think would happen if I did limit the browser width and the user was browsing with a smaller screen? Thanks!

Comment: like I said multiple times already: wrong approach. Dont try soemthign that is impossible and low quality in the first place. Simply give the body a min-width and overflow-x: scroll. Then you can define the minimum-width of your website and wont break your non-responsive design. If the browser is lower then the minimum width, it will get a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @tacoshy OK, thanks! However, I want to note that I am using a flexible/fluid layout, not a rigid fixed layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example with boxes next to each other which are broken because of a to small screen size. So they appear below each other instead of all next to each other.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

By simply adding `body { min-width: 1200px; overflow: auto/scroll; }` we define a minimum width for the website. That way now all boxes appear in one line. If the users browser is smaller than 1200px, they will get a horizontal scrollbar.

```css
body {
  min-width: 1200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

However using this method or what you try means a lack of skill and a low quality website as it is non-responsive. A good web developer will change the design with media queries to prevent an overflow or a min-width higher then 320px (smallest mobile screen width).

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The browser belongs to the user and they can do whatever they want with it.

But, OK, you sort of can if you are desperate. You can get the windows's current width with this bit of JavaScript:

```
var width = window.innerWidth;
```

You can then resize the window with:

```
window.resizeTo(800, 600)
```

Note - this only works if you created the window with `window.open()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo